# import LESS in LESS from several subdirectories

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

This scenario was testet in Visual Studio 2012 with the Web Essentials extension.

Filesystem:

> root\folder1\subfolder1\styles\main.less
>
> root\folder2\subfolder1\subfolder2\styles\fear.less

main.less:

```
@import "../../../folder2/subfolder1/subfolder2/styles/fear.less";
```

Compile Error:

> LESS: Couldn't load
>   folder2/subfolder1/subfolder2/styles/fear.less (404)

Is it possible that LESS does not support multiple subdirectories?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, along with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16786054/508702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now, I got it!
@Jeff's answer brought me to the following:

```
@import "..\..\..\folder2\subfolder1\subfolder2\styles\fear.less";
```

It also works for variables. You have to declare the whole filename including the extension.
No leading slash and only backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently a known bug/issue. In the meantime you can replace the forward slash in the import path with a backslash. That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, you have inspired me!