# Paths to images not generated correctly when importing .less files using Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

An issue I'm having with Web Essentials is that the paths to my images seems to be generated incorrectly. For example, when I have this structure:

```
/css
   main.less /* imports _sub.less */
   main.css /* generated */
/css/subfolder
   _sub.less
```

and _sub.less contains a reference to an images with `'../img/some/folder/myimage.jpg'`, it gets prefixed by the subfolder in the generated css file. Resulting in `'css/subfolder/../img/some/folder/myimage.jpg'`.

That is incorrect because ../img does not exist from the sub directory. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

try it like my that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934685/676406

```
@import "..\..\..\folder2\subfolder1\subfolder2\styles\fear.less";
```

No leading slash and only backslashes.

Comment: It works for the imports at least. I'll try if it works on the image paths as well. Thanks!